# Install Ubuntu alongside windows and something else

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

I am going to install ubuntu in my laptop in which windows is already installed. I tried installing Ubuntu once and quit the installation since I am not sure whether I should go for

```
install ubuntu alongside windows
```

or

```
something else
```

I need to the differences between these two options. In both options, I will have a dual boot to select which OS machine should boot from. right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Install Along Side

This option will automatically partition and install Ubuntu, including getting GRUB to have all the info needed to dual boot.

This is the easiest option to go for, and best for a beginner.

### Something Else

This option is much more advanced. It gives you control over partitioning and creating the Swap etc. You need to know what you're doing to ensure that everything is correct.

This is the advanced option, best for an experienced user.

Comment: yeah I am the one who asked a similar question similar day and you have answered for that also, thank you for that. thank you very much,. As you have pointed out in a comment for that question, installing alongside windows creates a swap automatically. Then I do not have anything to unsure about installing alongside. right? It will work as smooth as how an installation with a manually created swap works. Am I correct?

Comment: Should be very easy to do :)

Answer (score 1):

Something else is for more advanced users and should only be done if your a pro. Stick with Install alongside Windows.

Comment: I cannot accept two answers tho.. sry 4 dat